# Openbox - Set shortcut keys to change decor and layer attributes for active window

Tags: window-manager, openbox

In the Openbox window manager, is it possible to set a shortcut key combination to decorate/undecorate the active window, or change the layering of the active window (normal, above, below), or can this only be pre-defined in the config file with the `<decor>` and `<layer>` attributes?

If I have the window undecorated, then it's not possible to access the window layering icon (if set) to change the window from "normal" to "always on top". I might not always want a particular application set to always on top though, so setting it up in the config file isn't ideal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [OpenBox wiki](http://openbox.org/wiki/Main_Page) you can create a keybinding using the [`ToggleDecorations`](http://openbox.org/wiki/Help:Actions#ToggleDecorations) action to decorate/undecorate the active window and the [`SendToLayer`](http://openbox.org/wiki/Help:Actions#SendToLayer) action to move the window to a specified layer.

> ### ToggleDecorations
>
> Removes the window's decorations. If the  configuration
> option is enabled (as in the default configuraton), then a border will
> be left as the only decorations around the window. If the window has
> already had its decorations removed, then this will restore them.
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> <keybind key="W-F5">
>   <action name="ToggleDecorations"/>
> </keybind>
> ```

> ### SendToLayer
>
> Moves the window to the specified layer. Option   Default Value
> Description      normal  The layer to put the window in. It can
> be the "top" layer, which appears over all other windows except
> fullscreen windows, the "normal" layer, or the "bottom" layer, which
> appears below all other windows.
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> <keybind key="W-F7">
>  <action name="SendToLayer"><layer>top</layer></action>
> </keybind>
> ```